Min Pairing Heap - How to increase key faster than O(logn)?
I know that a min pairing heap can decrease a key faster than O(logn). However, is there any way to make the increase key operate also faster than decrease key to the top, remove, than insert new which time complexity is O(logn)? It seems no references talked about this.

In a binary heap, you can increase your key by taking the smaller of the two children, and if its smaller than the new node value, swapping it with your node and repeating the process. This is also O(log n) in the worst case, but in practice would be more efficient and faster. The implementation would be different for other heap implementations, and I suspect at least some of them would be O(1).

I've typically seen increase-key and decrease-key treated as the same thing in discussions of heaps.
In a pairing min heap, decrease-key has amortized runtime complexity of O(log n). There are cases when the operation is very quick and cases when it's very expensive, but overall it's O(log n). increase-key, too, has cases when it's O(1), and cases when it's more expensive than O(log n).
The way decrease-key is normally implemented is:

Delete the key from the pairing heap. This involves doing a remove-min on that sub-heap (i.e. the heap formed with that node as the root). The full two-pass pairing operation is done on that sub-heap.
Decrease the key.
Insert the key at the top of the heap.

Not surprisingly, increase-key is implemented in exactly the same way. But as you noted: if we're increasing the value of the key there's no real reason to insert it at the top of the heap: the key can't possibly move towards the root if you increase it.
You could modify increase-key so that in step 3 it inserts the key into the heap right back where it was. Treat the node that replaced it as the root of a sub-heap and insert.
For example, consider this pairing heap. 3 is the root. 4,7,3,5,8 are its children, etc. You want to increase the key 5 to the value 7.
 3
 |
 4,7,3,5,8
 |     |  
 5     9,8,12,6

So first delete it:
 3
 |
 4,7,3,6,8
 |     |  
 5     8,12
       |
       9

And then insert it, treating the replacement node (6) as the root of the heap you're inserting it into:
 3
 |
 4,7,3,6,8
 |     |  
 5     8,12,7
       |
       9

It's unclear to me how much that would save you, if anything. The expensive part of the operation (removing the key) is the same in both. And inserting is O(1) in both cases. The only difference is that with the normal way the key is inserted as a child of the root. With the optimization, the key is inserted as a child of a node further down in the heap. The immediate cost of the operation is identical, regardless of which way you do it.
Whether that will save you any time overall is hard to say. You'd think that because the optimization keeps the node in a lower level of the heap, the overall effect would be to improve performance because it's one less node that has to be sifted down through the heap over the many remove-min operations that will follow. But pairing heap's behavior is sometimes difficult to predict.
Whatever the case, although you can potentially make some optimizations that will reduce the running time in specific cases, it's quite unlikely that you'll reduce the average-case complexity of O(log n).
